# In LESS, is it possible to import one selector's content into another one?

Tags: css, less

My goal is to import the `content: '\e826';` from an icon class into another selector in case that content property changes in the future.

```
.icon-hi:before {content: '\e826';}

.panel {
    background: white;
    .panel-title {
        &:before {
            @include .icon-hi;
            text-align: center;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
        }
    }
}
```

Of course `@import` doesn't work for that, but is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

For the purpose of defining a value in one place, you should use variables:

```
@icon-hi: '\e826';

.icon-hi:before {content: @icon-hi;}

.panel {
    background: white;
    .panel-title {
        &:before {
            content: @icon-hi;
            text-align: center;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
        }
    }
}
```

You can actually 'import one selector into another'. This is basically what mixins do. These are the first two features in the less documentation - http://lesscss.org/features/

A third option is to use the extend feature: http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature

Comment: Thanks Ali, although that would make updating my icon classes harder. I currently bundle icons in fontello and drop all the updated `.icon-` classes in. Was hoping I could reference the classes content. Looking like it's not possible though without vars.

Comment: I updated my answer with some more options. You should look into mixins as well as extend. You might try something like `.panel-title:extend(.icon-hi all)`

Comment: The best option is if the library you are using has a less source, you can include the source with your own and use their variables directly and compile them all together

Comment: Boom! Extend did the trick! Ended up with...
`.panel-title { /* styles */ &:extend(.icon-hi all); &:before {text-align:center; /* etc /*}}`.  Many thanks Ali!

Answer (score 1):

You can, here's the example:

```
.icon-hi{
  &:before{
    content: '\e826';
  }
}

.panel {
    background: white;
    .panel-title {
    .icon-hi;
            &:before {
                text-align: center;
                width: 20px;
                height: 20px;
            }
        }
    }
```

You have to define .icon-hi class and define before with nesting so the preproccessor can know what to fetch.